# Passing base64 encoded username and password through a https (SSL) connection for a mobile website

Tags: security

Whether passing a base64 encoded username and passwords as variables through a secured SSL connection for a mobile website is safe?

Whether I should encode it with AES256?

For eachwebpage I fetch a url with base64 encoded username and password like this

https://mobile.site.com?id=ASDQWEQWEQWEQWEQWE  (Where id contains username and password)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL is the way to go and will send that data encrypted, so it cannot be read by anyone along the stream. Encrypting it beforehand using AES would require you to pre-exchange keys with both your client and your server, which would be an added step that you would need to do out-of-channel; the asymmetric nature of the key exchange done in SSL makes this unnecessary.

And...do NOT hash the password on the client side and just send to the server to compare. This is a horrible practice. If your server's username/password table were to be compromised, an attacker would know exactly what to send to your server to log in as any user (user A has hash X, so just send A/X as UN/PW and the server will let you in). You want to send the actual password to the server, so it can hash it there and then compare the result to the stored value (user A has hash X, but I cannot figure out what value hashes to X so I don't know what to send as the PW).

Comment: If the users table on a server is compromised then an attacker quite likely already has access to all accounts (if necessary, he could just change a password in the table). Your least problem would be having an attacker logging in user accounts then..

Comment: Consider the read attack on the table, not write. If all credentials are stored as salted hashes of the passwords, then (theoretically), there is no real compromise at all as an attacker will not be able to go from the salted hashes back to the passwords they will need to supply to the server in order to access the accounts. Having a list of usernames and salted hashes of passwords is approximately equal to just having a list of usernames since the hashes would need to be cracked which is very difficult given good salt+algorithm.

Comment: If someone has write access to your server, all bets are off regardless of whatever solution to this case you care about. That is no reason to not protect the user credentials and integrity of the login process using the best design possible.

Comment: Whether the secure connection is still safe because the url passes through opera mini which routes the traffic through proxy servers!!

Comment: Proxy servers should not be decrypting/breaking the SSL tunnel. If they are, then the SSL connection will terminate at the proxy server. You should always be able to tell where you SSL encrypted tunnel ends based on the cert presented as connection time. So, the name of the SSL certificate your client is connecting to will not match the site it is trying to connect to (as it is talking to the proxy instead of the site). If you're using a browser on the client, you'll see that Name Mismatch error and the SSL session won't be created (unless the user explicitly chooses to).

Answer (score 1):

If you use SSL to connect then all the content, including passwords and usernames is already encoded.
Not necessarily with AES256, but that depends on the cipher suite used.
There is no need to additionally encode them, using SSL is perfectly fine.

Encoding it with Base64 is optional - it's a transparent encoding that does not add any additional security, it's just meant for easier data transmission (e.g. special characters in usernames or passwords).

Comment: The problem is I get content of a page each time by using a url like this http://mobile.site.com?id=AEASDASDASDASDASDASD=

Where AEASDASDASDASDASDASD is my base64 encoded username and password..

And also when the user access the url using Opera mobile urls may get stored on their proxy server along with base64 encoded strings right?

Comment: You should store that information in a cookie instead. But what is the problem you mention?

Comment: Do NOT hash the password on the client side and just send to the server to compare. This is a horribly insecure practice. See my answer for details.

Comment: Sending UN/PW over SSL to a server and having it hash the password w/ salt and compare to stored salted hash is a very standard design pattern and is a secure practice.

Comment: It's secure..but what's the need to send it everytime when the webpage is fetched..I don't think that's a secure practice

Comment: You don't. Send it once, validate the login information is correct, then generate a session cookie to send to the client which they will provide back on every request. See here for guidance - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management.